# Erro de compilação, Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, compilação

Compilador aponta o seguinte erro:
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0`

Logo após aponta para a linha do if

```
public class Pilha extends Lista {
    public Pilha(int tamanho){
this.tamanho=tamanho;
}
    public int[] elementos=new int[this.tamanho];
    public int push(int n){
    for(int i=0;i<this.tamanho;i++){
    if(elementos[i]=='0'){/*aqui*/
    this.insert(i,n);
    System.out.println("Valor inserido");
```

Também aponta para a chamada de função:
`pilhaInstance.push(10);`
Detalhe:o Compilador só aponta erro quando chamo a função, caso contrário compila normalmente.
Não sei o que estou errando pois sou iniciante no java porém estou vendo e revendo esse código e não acho nada.